# Bootstrap 3.3.2 mobile nav submenu buttons not showing under parent buttons on click

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am looking to fix my mobile nav in bootstrap 3.3 to show submenu items on click. The parent buttons shouldn't link to anything, just show the children links.

The navigation currently will not show submenu links when clicking the parent link when in mobile (works fine in desktop resolutions on hover). It appears the submenu links show in tablet resolution, then hide in mobile.

I can't tell if they appear and are just hidden, or if they don't show at all. When I add css to display the children automatically, they show up fine where they belong. It's only when they need to be clicked to show that they don't work. Here is the link to the nav and some code for the navigation. Is there some javascript click function that is missing?

Here is a link to the working nav: https://patrick-diaz.com/navtest/

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Bootstrap 3.3 documentation, it works perfectly & it's also responsive for mobile view.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#navbar